# How to do Crash Reporting for Web Apps

Tags: javascript, html, crash, reporting, onerror

When I develop iPhone / iPad apps I always use a crash reporting system. My current favorite is [Crashlytics](http://crashlytics.com/) - which works great.

For Android apps I've been using the rather more basic [ACRA](http://acra.ch/) crash reporter.

Now that I'm building a webapp to be run on a client's own server, it seems a good idea to build in some kind of crash reporting system, probably linked off the window.onerror event.

Of course, I could build my own system. But does anyone know a good drop-in solution that sends and collates reports?

Incidentally, I'd prefer a completely client-side solution (i.e. just JavaScript) rather than anything that requires server support.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both Exceptional and Airbrake offer javascript implementations

- [Airbrake](http://airbrakeapp.com/)
- [Exceptional](http://www.exceptional.io/)

**Update**

Exceptional was officially shut down in favor of Airbrake ([Source](https://github.com/exceptional/exceptional))

Comment: Thanks Tim, I'll check those out. Looks like the AirBrake one is experimental so might not put that into production quite yet :-)

Comment: Also checkout [TrackJS](https://trackjs.com/). The tricky bit about crash reporting for JavaScript is that the errors themselves don't give you enough context to really understand what happened. TrackJS captures this extra context to give you recreation steps of the bug.

Comment: Please do not edit my answer to add your own product. Instead, write **your own answer** and explain in detail why your product is better.

Answer (score 3):

Whilst not currently supported by iOS, a number of [browser platforms now support](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_reportingobserver) the [W3C Reporting API](https://w3c.github.io/reporting/) which can be useful for reporting of crash and other analytics. For some examples see the [MDN page on the Reporting API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Reporting_API).

Comment: interesting - thanks! I didn't know that existed until now